# Why can I only upload one file using Play and uploadify?

Tags: java, javascript, image, playframework, uploadify

I wrote this [simple Play-uploadify demo](https://github.com/ripper234/play-uploadify).

I want to an upload button that automatically upload an image each time its pressed.

For some reason, only the first time the button is pressed, I get an upload. After the button has been pressed once, further presses do not cause anything unless I "cancel" the previous uploads.

(I don't understand the meaning of canceling an upload with `auto` mode. Perhaps the problem is that my downloads never "complete" in some sense?)

Here is my action method:

```
public static void upload(File file, long userId){
    System.out.println("Uploaded file name " + file.getName() + 
      " by user " + userId);
}
```

And the call to uploadify:

```
$(function() {
    $("#uploader").uploadify({
        uploader    : '/public/libraries/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        script      : '/Application/upload',
        cancelImg   : '/public/libraries/uploadify/cancel.png',
        folder      : '/uploads',
        fileExt     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
        fileDesc    : 'Image Files',
        fileDataName: 'file',
        scriptData: {userId: 123},
        auto: true
    });
});
```

Also, the upload never seems to complete - when I add an `onComplete` handler, it does't fire.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not returning a HTTP `200` status code, because I didn't call any render method or return a value at the end of my action method.

Adding `renderText("OK");` resolved my problem.

`ok();` is a neater way of resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

try to change it to

```
    script      : '/application/upload',
```

(notice the lowercase a in application... play always generates lowercase urls when you use the default route.)

as for only being able to upload one file at a time:

have you tested the upload in dev or production mode?
 in dev mode, the amount of threads available for processing is one,
 so it will block as soon as you want to upload a second file at the same moment

Comment: I'm working in dev mode - but the problem does not seem to be related to Play threads. The Play action method contains just a `println()`, and immediately returns. Even after it completes, the client is not able to even start uploading another file. Perhaps I should render something for Uploadify to understand I handle the upload correctly?

Comment: hmm... it just returns? 
you should do at least a ok() at the end of the action.